# Jackson Deserializing From CSV to Enum

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize from a football results csv to an enum using Jackson's dataformat library. This is the csv file (the sixth column is the one I'm interested in):

```
Egypt,Uruguay,GROUP,2,0,HOME
```

This is my enum class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public enum MatchOutcome {

    HOME(3, 0),
    DRAW(1, 1),
    AWAY(0, 3),
    HOME_ET(1, 1),
    AWAY_ET(1, 1),
    HOME_PENS(1, 1),
    AWAY_PENS(1, 1);

    private final Integer homePoints;
    private final Integer awayPoints;

    MatchOutcome(Integer homePoints, Integer awayPoints) {
        this.homePoints = homePoints;
        this.awayPoints = awayPoints;
    }

    public Integer homePoints() {
        return this.homePoints;
    }

    public Integer awayPoints() {
        return this.awayPoints;
    }
}
```

And this is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder()
            .addColumn("HOME")
            .addColumn("AWAY")
            .addColumn("STAGE")
            .addColumn("HOME_FULL_TIME")
            .addColumn("AWAY_FULL_TIME")
            .addColumn("MATCH_OUTCOME")
            .build();

    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

    File csvFile = new File("src/Resources/fixtureResult.csv");

    MappingIterator<MatchOutcome> matchOutcomeIterator = csvMapper.readerFor(MatchOutcome.class).with(csvSchema)
            .readValues(csvFile);


    while (matchOutcomeIterator.hasNextValue()) {

        MatchOutcome matchOutcome = matchOutcomeIterator.nextValue();
        System.out.println(matchOutcomeIterator.toString());

    }

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.football.Calculator.MatchOutcome` out of START_OBJECT token
```

Are my annotations wrong? Or do I need a toString method on my Enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a wrapper class and mapped to that in the end,

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MatchOutcomeWrapper {

public MatchOutcome matchOutcome;

public MatchOutcomeWrapper(@JsonProperty("MATCH_OUTCOME") MatchOutcome matchOutcome) {
    this.matchOutcome = matchOutcome;
}

public MatchOutcome getMatchOutcome() {
    return matchOutcome;
}

public String toString() {

    return new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE)
            .append("matchOutcome", matchOutcome)
            .toString();
}
}
```